# Noob here, how can I rig up a button to the GPIO, and set it so that it will trigger a key press?

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I'm quite new to the GPIO portion of the raspberry pi, and I am wondering how to rig up something that will detect button presses. I have a model b+ (40 pin). Which pins do I wire it to? How do I even start on the software component?

My goal is to have the button pulse trigger the escape key.

I can't find much on the Internet that is at my level and works for b+, sadly. Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit: more things after doing more research. What's this about pull up resistors? What do they do? Do I need one, and where should I put it?

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials/articles. Do some more research then ask a specific question if you need help.

Comment: @milliways I have searched quite a bit, but I am having trouble finding specific information.

Comment: @Blue_Dragon360 Just as an FYI, anything that works on a Model B or Model A will work on a Model B+. Just because it's a different hardware model doesn't mean the software is incompatible. So long as the software installed is the same, any of those tutorials will work for the B+ just dandy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - there are several libraries on the web. I like [Pikeyd](https://github.com/mmoller2k/pikeyd), which I used in my 2 MAMEs.

Piked:

Installing pikeyd ([from my tutorial](http://phillystutorials.blogspot.com))

pikeyd is a c program which translates the GPIO HI/LOW to keyboard presses. I've done a bit of research and tried a few programs that do the same thing as pikeyd, but pikeyd is by far the best.

```
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/mmoller2k/pikeyd.git
$ cd pikeyd
$ sudo make 
$ sudo modprobe uinput 
$ sudo cp pikeyd /usr/local/bin/pikeyd
```

pikeyd needs a config file to map the key presses to GPIO pins

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pikeyd.conf
```

and paste the following code and save

```
#pikeyd.conf

#format:
# {keycode from /usr/include/linux/input.h} {GPIO pin no}
# Not limited to a single key. A GPIO press will emit all defined keys in order.
KEY_UP         8
KEY_DOWN       7
KEY_LEFT        17
KEY_RIGHT       11
KEY_1  24
KEY_ESC 18

KEY_5 25
KEY_2 22
KEY_LEFTCTRL 27
KEY_LEFTALT 4

KEY_ENTER 3
```

Now, lets make sure pikeyd start when we boot up

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following line before exit 0

```
/usr/local/bin/pikeyd -d
```

Save the file:
Ctrl+X to exit, Y to save followed by enter twice

Now we want to launch the uinput module every time we boot up automatically:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Scroll to the bottom of the file and add:

```
uinput
```

Save the file:
Ctrl+X to exit, Y to save followed by enter twice

As for pull up resistor: before you start wiring up your GPIO, you should read up Ohms Laws and Resistors. If you don't use pull up or pull down resistors with your GPIO, you can fry your Raspberry Pi. The numbers in the `picked.conf` are your GPIO pin numbers:

```
KEY_UP         8
```

'KEY_UP' is of course, the key up key and 8 is your GPIO pin