# Game controller to keyboard and mouse

Tags: raspbian

I am running raspberry pi 4. I am working on turning it into a gaming console that is able to interact with my raspberry pi as if I was using a keyboard and mouse. Is there any program that would let me use a controller as a keyboard/mouse? I have already looked at several programs but they have not been compatible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an interesting project, one I want to do as well with a wiimote. Connecting the controller is the easy part, but using it as a keyboard is the hard part. I found this link [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23991/noob-here-how-can-i-rig-up-a-button-to-the-gpio-and-set-it-so-that-it-will-tri/23995) that might help with triggering the keyboard inputs, but is triggered by GPIO inputs. I think this can be easily changes from GPIO sensing to Wiimote(or other controllers) button sensing. The link [here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/02/nintendo-wii-remote-python-and-the-raspberry-pi/) gives you step by step instructions to connecting a Wiimote, as well as working code you can copy+paste right into your pi. If want to use a different controller, I'd recommend Bluetooth or USB. I know someone who has code for a Logitech Gamepad if you want it. To use this effectively, you'd want it to initiate upon startup, which I don't know how to do, but I'm sure there are tutorials out there. Keep in mind that you will probably only be able to get 1 key per button, but I'm sure there's a way to fix it somehow with some coding. i.e.-

```
if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_PLUS):
  if keyboard_set <5:
    keyboard_set = keyboard_set + 1
  if keyboard_set = 5:
    keyboard_set = 1
  time.sleep(button_delay)

if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_A):
  if keyboard_set = 1:
    #insert code to trigger 'A' key here
  if keyboard_set = 2:
    #insert code to trigger 'B' key here
  if keyboard_set = 3:
    #insert code to trigger 'C' key here
  if keyboard_set = 4:
    #insert code to trigger 'D' key here
  if keyboard_set = 5:
    #insert code to trigger 'E' key here
  time.sleep(button_delay)
```

*this code is for wiimote. change the if criteria depending on your controller*

Anyways, you get the idea. Once you figure out how to trigger the keys, it should come pretty easily after that. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Install `qjoypad`. Then connect an USB controller with it. If you are using `retroarch` then you have to download and configure profile.

Comment: I really like this idea better than writing custom code.